# Make a Wordpress post/page password protected by default

Tags: wordpress

Hi my name is Olga and I'm trying to make a Wordpress post/page password protected by default. Has anyone an idea how to make it? I only found private by default but not password protected.

Comment: Have you tried making any modifications via the `save_post` hook to change the meta to make it protected by default?

Comment: Please, show us some code that you've already made.

Comment: I have this code! Unfortunately all posts are password protected now and i can not make one public.
`add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'so_13517851_filter_handler' , '99', 2 );

function so_13517851_filter_handler( $data , $postarr )
{
    // creating new post and correct post_type
    if( empty( $data['post_name'] ) && 'post' == $postarr['post_type'] || 'team-member' == $postarr['post_type'] || 'page' == $postarr['post_type'] )
        $data[ 'post_password' ] = wp_generate_password();

    return $data;
}`